# The area of the faces of a right rectangular prism are 24, 32, and 48 square centimeters. What is the volume of the prism?

Tags: volume, area

Can someone show me their work, and not just the answer? I need to learn how to do this, and showing work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you drawn a picture? That would be my first piece of advice.

Answer (score 1):

To find the volume given three face areas, we let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be the dimensions of the prism. Now, $ab = 24$, $ac = 32$, and $bc = 48$. Combining them, we get $(abc)^2 = 24 \cdot 32 \cdot 48$. So, $abc = \sqrt{24 \cdot 32 \cdot 48} = \sqrt{36864}$. This is exactly **192**.

To solve for any volume given 3 faces, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are face areas, the formula is $V = \sqrt{xyz}$.

Answer (score 0):

Start by assigning variables to things, and writing down equations for what you know.

Let's say the box has length $L$, width $W$, and height $H$. Then, we are given:

$L \cdot W = 24$

$W \cdot H = 32$

$H \cdot L = 48$

We want the volume of the box, which is $V = L \cdot W \cdot H$. Can you figure out how to compute that?

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd compute that.

Comment: Would I compute it like such: V = WHL = 32 x 48 x 24 = 36864?

Comment: How did you get $WHL = 32 \cdot 48 \cdot 24$ from those equations? That isn't quite correct.

Comment: I just took a guess.

Comment: You should try to use those three equations (which is the information the problem gave you) instead of guessing. Have you tried multiplying those three equations?

Comment: How would I set it up? I'm not understanding what LW, WH, HL are exactly. I understand L = length, W = width, and H= height.

Comment: I know that 24 x 32 x 48 = 36864. Is there another step I'm not taking in account for?

Comment: @Bev  The 36864 is the *square* of the volume, since in multiplying the areas of the three sides each edge appears twice as a factor.